# Accessing columns of a dataframe withing a large list of dataframes in R

Tags: r

So I've been struggling to figure this out. I'm still quite new to R and haven't found a solution here yet.

I have a `data.frame` which looks like this:

```
LandAverageTemperature LandAverageTemperatureUncertainty       date year
1     3.0340000000000003                             3.574 1750-01-01 1750
2                  3.083                             3.702 1750-02-01 1750
3                  5.626                             3.076 1750-03-01 1750
4                   8.49                             2.451 1750-04-01 1750
5                 11.573                             2.072 1750-05-01 1750
6     12.937000000000001                             1.724 1750-06-01 1750
```

So what I want to do is: for every year, I want to get the mean of the `LandAverageTemperature` column.

I tried to do this using the `split` function first like this:

```
df_list <- split(cleanGlobalTemps, f = cleanGlobalTemps$year)
```

That leaves me a large list of 266 elements(one for each year from 1750 until 2016). I want to loop through each `dataframe` in this list and get the mean of the `LandAverageTemperature` column.

I tried this:

```
for(i in 1:length(df_list)){
  averageYearlyGlobalTemp[i] <- mean(as.double(df_list[[i]][[1]]), na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

But that doesn't work, it returns results as follows:

```
> averageYearlyGlobalTemp
  [1] 1320.1667  709.6667  973.1667 1319.7500 1120.9167 1300.2500 1368.9167 1365.7500 1133.5833 1335.8333 1056.8333
 [12] 1336.4167 1543.8333 1004.5000 1139.7500 1435.0000 1404.8333 1288.7500 1239.6667 1282.7500 1345.9167 1313.1667
 [23] 1469.5000 1273.2500 1151.7500 1304.0000
```

....and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aggregate` allows you to compute statistics by group

```
aggregate(cleanGlobalTemps$LandAverageTemperature, by=list(cleanGlobalTemps$year), FUN=mean)
```

Comment: This looks really promising. One issue is how can I pass in the na.rm = TRUE parameter via the mean function? Because all my results are NA with this method.

Comment: You should be able to just add it to the function

`aggregate(cleanGlobalTemps$LandAverageTemperature, by=list(cleanGlobalTemps$year), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: That was what occurred to me just afterwards and I tried that but no dice unfortunately.

Comment: averageYearlyGlobalTemp <- aggregate(cleanGlobalTemps$LandAverageTemperature, by=list(cleanGlobalTemps$year), FUN=mean, na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: Well the function works as intended on my own data, so I'd expect something prior to that in your code is wonky. Only thing I can think of without seeing what else you're doing is maybe LandAverageTemperature isn't set as numeric?

Comment: Solved it! Will edit it into my question but I had to use the levels() function as my column was a factor and the as.numeric or as.double commands were returning the integer value of the factor. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(LandAverageTemperature)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise( output = mean(LandAverageTemperature) )
```

Comment: I am working with the primary dataframe not the list of dataframes. I think making the list of dataframes isn't necessary.

Comment: ***Accessing columns of a dataframe withing a large list of dataframes in R*** read the title.

Comment: I read the title but the I think the main question is different with the title!

Comment: I tried this but again got an output of all NAs in the output column. I added in the na.rm = TRUE parameter in the mean function but it made no difference.

Comment: Also apologies if my title wasn't the most accurate. My first stackoverflow post! As I mentioned I tried your suggestion @ShahabEinabadi, like so:
cleanGlobalTemps %>% 
      group_by(year) %>%
      summarise( output = mean(LandAverageTemperature, na.rm = TRUE) ) but all the output column is just NA

Comment: @ShahabEinabadi thanks I managed to solve it using Mr. Bugle's code below. Couldn't get it working with your code but please see my edit above for the working solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

So thanks for the help all. @Mr. Bugle below suggested code which was promising but I couldn't get the answer correct. So it turned out because I was dealing with factors, I needed to use the levels() function to get access to the proper value within the column.

Here is the final working code:

`averageYearlyGlobalTemp <- aggregate(as.numeric(levels(cleanGlobalTemps$LandAverageTemperature)[cleanGlobalTemps$LandAverageTemperature]), by=list(cleanGlobalTemps$year), FUN=mean, na.rm = TRUE)`